# How to pass parameter to PowerBI Embedded Report

Tags: r, database, postgresql, powerbi, data-visualization

I have a IFrame which shows a PowerBI embedded Report having Accounts Data and I am  taking two inputs from user as Start Date and End Date through UI and according to those inputs my Database table is being populated with a unique ID for that selection. Can I pass a parameter to PowerBI Embedded via embedded URL to filter my report based on that input and unique ID for current selection in UI.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you only need prefiltering, and not data security, this doc may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't filter the data using `embeddedUrl`. You should use [filters](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters) to achieve that. Let's say you have a table named `AccountsData` in your model, and a column named `DatesId` in it. When you embed the report in your application, define a filter for this column, e.g. like this:

```
const basicFilter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
    target: {
        table: "AccountsData",
        column: "DatesId"
    },
    operator: "In",
    values: [1],
    filterType: models.FilterType.BasicFilter
}
```

And then pass this filter in [embed configuration details](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details):

```
var config = {
    type: embedType,
    accessToken: accessToken,
    tokenType: tokenType,
    embedUrl: embedUrl,
    id: embedId,
    dashboardId: dashboardId,
    permissions: permissions,
    filters: [basicFilter],
    settings: {
        filterPaneEnabled: true,
        navContentPaneEnabled: true
    }
};
```

where `1` is the unique ID for that selection. Change it every time, when the report is shown in your application (i.e. 2, 3, 4, etc.).

More information on how to filter data with Power BI Embedded can be found in [Filters](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters) documentation.